# Firebase Phone Auth (Android)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I developed an app but I have problem with Firebase Phone Auth.Firebase do not sending SMS.The following situations is observed while testing:

- SMS code delivered in Debug apk (in some cases)
- SMS code is not delivered in Release apk

Already added SHA-1 from Play Console,updated google-service.json file after adding SHA-1,commented the super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken) but still no luck.As far as I understood I don't have problem with code because it's actually sending sms in some situation.
P.S Tested number with https://fir-ui-demo-84a6c.firebaseapp.com/ the sms successfully send.

```
PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks=new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {

        Log.d("verificationcompleted","true:"+phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode());
        String code = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();
        codeauthtxt.setText(code);
        authverified=1;
        writeNewUser(uname,surname,phonenum,password,sex,authverified);

    }

    @Override
    public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
        Log.d("verificationcompleted","error"+e.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
        //super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
        Log.d("verificationcompleted","codesent:"+s);
        codesent=s;

    }
```

Comment: SMS will not sending to virtual devices, but test phone number will still working, so you need to test SMS receiving in real device.

Comment: I tried them all in real device.No luck((